# SignalR issue when using Redis scaleOut

Tags: asp.net, redis, signalr

I'm working on signalR project and I want to scale out signalr using redis by following the steps in the official documentation.The problem is that when I use only signalr the application works fine: signalr client is sending three requests to the server – negotiate, connect and start but when adding this line:
" hubConfiguration.Resolver.UseRedis(new RedisScaleoutConfiguration("localhost", 6379, string.Empty, "MyApp"))" in my startup the signalr client sends only negociate and connect with response status code:200 but don't send the start request. My statrtup looks as the following:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.Map("/signalr", map =>
        {
            map.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
            HubConfiguration hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration();
            hubConfiguration.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
            hubConfiguration.EnableJavaScriptProxies = false;
            hubConfiguration.EnableJSONP = true;
            GlobalHost.Configuration.TransportConnectTimeout = 
            TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
            hubConfiguration.Resolver.UseRedis(new 
            RedisScaleoutConfiguration("localhost", 6379, string.Empty, 
            "TrainApp"));
            map.RunSignalR(hubConfiguration);
        });
    }
}
```